# how to change mail-to email in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, vs-web-site-project

My friend has a Wordpress website and she has no idea how to change anything so she asks me. How can I change the default contact email address?

This is the one that appear on the top bar, sort of towards the left. If you click on it, it opens your default email program. I'm looking in the Wordpress settings but I don't see where it is saved.

I am logging in as the site admin and looking for the setting. I'm not looking at the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you mean by top bar - left. There is no email there in WP admin. But the default email for WP admin is under `Settings > General > Email Address` when you are in the admin section. For the logged in user email you can click on your icon top right and select the `Edit my profile` menu option.

If by "top left" you are referring to the frontend of the site (as opposed to admin) then its a custom thing that the theme placed there. Themes are developed by independent authors and not part of the core WP and many themes have their own settings panel (which makes finding certain settings difficult as the theme author placed it wherever they wanted). Oftentimes the theme has its own menu entry in admin so look for that.

Additionally since you mention "contact email address" perhaps there is a contact form on the site. By default WP has no contact form so these are added by plugins. Most likely they make use of the administrator email addressI mentioned first but can also be overridden. The place to look depends on the form plugin but common ones might be Contact Form 7 which I think places its settings under the Settings menu. Another popular one is Gravity Form which has its own entry in admin.

Hope that helps.